# Watermark function returns true but the image is not modified

Tags: php, codeigniter

All I am trying to do is watermark an image on upload. Although the watermark function returns `TRUE` the image is not modified.

This is the function I wrote, even with try and catch it's not working:

```
 public function product_small_image_upload($path, $folder)
{

    try {
        $image = new ImageResize($path);
        $image->quality_jpg = 85;
        $image->resizeToHeight(300);
        $new_name = 'img_x300_' . generate_unique_id() . '.jpg';
        $new_path = 'uploads/' . $folder . '/' . $new_name;

        $imgConfig = array();

        $imgConfig['image_library']   = 'GD2';

        $imgConfig['source_image']    = $new_path;

        $imgConfig['wm_text']         = 'Copyright 2019';

        $imgConfig['wm_type']         = 'text';

        $imgConfig['wm_font_size']    = '16';

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $imgConfig);

        $this->image_lib->initialize($imgConfig);

        $this->image_lib->watermark(); 

        $image->save(FCPATH . $new_path, IMAGETYPE_JPEG);

        return $new_name;
    } catch (ImageResizeException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

- The `$new_path` variable contains this string `upload/images/img_x300_1289.png`, the name being randomly generated.
- I also tried  `base_url().$new_path` because I thought that I have to be more specific about the image path but it is still not working.
- How can I see what doesn't work, why the image gets no watermark even tho' I am doing this on upload?

Comment: Try `echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();` to get the errors if there is any.

Comment: the function returns ``true`` so there shouldn't be any error but I will try

Answer (score 1):

First add  $new_path = FCPATH . 'uploads/' . $folder . '/' . $new_name;

You don't need to use  $imgConfig['image_library'], and  you haven't use aligment of the water mark .

why DOn't you use the correct way like this:

```
$config['source_image'] = $new_path;
$config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright 2019';
$config['wm_type'] = 'text';
$config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
$config['wm_font_size'] = '8';
$config['wm_font_color'] = '000000';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
```

use this code and you willl get the water mark just choose the color of the text you want